# ggplot error: geom_point unknown colour name

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df:

```
   text  cost type 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    23 h    
2     2    12 p    
3     3     3 h    
4     4    14 p    
5     5    21 h    
6     6     6 p
```

And I'm trying to use geom_point to automatically assign colours based on `data1$type`.

```
ggplot(data1,(aes(x=reorder(text,-cost),y=(cost))))+geom_point(colour=data1$type)
```

But I get the error:

```
Unknown colour name: h
```

It seems as if it needs a specific colour, but I'm pretty sure this isn't the case. Is there a way to automatically assign colour based on my type column?

Comment: Try `ggplot(data1, aes(x=reorder(text,-cost), y=cost))+geom_point(aes(colour=type))`. BTW: You don't need all the braces.

Comment: Using `aes` for the colour tells ggplot to treat colour as a variable that is dependent of your data (and look this up in your data), otherwise colour is treated as a fixed value